# Interpolating a three point curve at any angle using cubic splines

Tags: interpolation, plane-curves, spline

I'm trying to interpolate a curve using cubic splines and three points in the x-y plane. I have some troubles finding the equation for the middle point such that the normal vectors in point P0 is always perpendicular to the x-axis, given any angle between the yellow line and the x-axis. See figure: [Spline curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K94qG.png)

P0 is always known, P1 is given by:

P_1 = [r1*cos(beta); r1*sin(beta)], where r1 is the the length of the yellow line and beta is the angle between the yellow line and the x-axis. In the image above I have experimentally found the equations for P2, which is:

P2 = [0.75*P1_x; 0.25*P1_y]. But this only works if beta is 45 degrees. I've tried to reverse engineer it but I failed miserably. How would I go about finding the equations for P2?

Best regards MC

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are:
$$ x(t_L) = y(t_L) = y'(t_L) = 0 $$
$$ x(t_R) = r_1 \cos(\beta) $$
$$ y(t_R) = r_1 \sin(\beta) $$
For convenience we can set $t_L = 0$, $t_R = 1$.  Then for a cubic spline we have
$$ x(t) = a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + a_3t^3 $$
$$ y(t) = b_0 + b_1t + b_2t^2 + b_3t^3 $$
$$ x(0) = a_0 = 0 $$
$$ y(0) = b_0 = 0 $$
$$ y'(0) = b_1 = 0 $$
$$ x(1) = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = r_1 \cos(\beta) $$
$$ y(1) = b_2 + b_3 = r_1 \sin(\beta) $$
Unless you have other constraints in mind that you haven't told us, there appear to be three extra degrees of freedom; you could set $ a_2 = a_3 = b_3 = 0 $, for simplicity.

Do you want the curve to be vertical at P1?  Then
$$ x'(1) = a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3 = 0 $$
but still there are two degrees of freedom, and you could set $ a_3 = b_3 = 0 $ whence 
$$ a_1 = 2 r_1 \cos(\beta) $$
$$ a_2 = -r_1 \cos(\beta) $$

Now, why do you need P2?  Once you've chosen the coefficients for the spline, you can set P2 to $( x(\frac{1}{2}), y(\frac{1}{2}) )$.